# how to use for each for json arrays in angular4

Tags: angular

[image]

this is my array ,i got this after push values to the array. My problem is i try to  print each values using for loop and for each but its not works .

```
for (let asd of this.data){
  console.log("check")
  console.log(asd);
}  

this.data.forEach((test,index) =>{
  console.log(test+"_"+index);
 });
```

i did't get any result.. is any wrong ?

Comment: try this     `this.data.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.user_id + element.email)
    });`

Comment: @NJ : Would you mind creating  a stackblitz demo.

Comment: When ask question please put realistic data not image

Comment: Please check with `console.log(this.data);` before `for` loop. Whether it is populated or not.

Comment: There is only one reason, your data isn't populated before entering in loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this StackBlitz example: [Array Looping](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nq3kmu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  name = 'Angular';

  array = [
    { "user_id": 22, "email": "email1" },
    { "user_id": 23, "email": "email2" }
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    for (let item of this.array) {
      console.log(item);
    }
  }
}
```